# set selected value from the database to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oracle11g

I am entering data into a database from my jsp page and I have a drop down that looks like this:

```
<select name="marital" size="1" id="marital" class="textboxes">
<option selected value="">SELECT</option>
<option value="M">MARRIED</option>
<option value="S">SINGLE</option>
<option value="D">DIVORCED</option>
<option value="W">WIDOWED</option>
<option value="U">UNKNOWN</option>
</select>
```

While editing this record, I need for example if I inserted SINGLE to have it as the selected value on my edit screen: My fetch method:

```
public static String getMaritalStatus(String custid) {
        String str = "";
        try {
            Connection conn = con.getDbConnection();
            String sql = "select marital_status from customer_table where cust_id = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, custid);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                str = rs.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return str;
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, there are number of ways to do so - JavaScript, Rewrite html attributes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do that. Just add the following to your JSP.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#marital").val( '${maritalStatus}' );
    });
</script>
```

where `${maritalStatus}` is an EL in the JSP for the marital status.

Comment: Did you have in the request scope the value for the marital status. In my example, the name of that value is `maritalStatus`. See the generate HTML source. By the way, I added quoutes in my answer.

Comment: Yes. I am passsing that as a session attribute.

Answer (score -2):

function edit() {
        var marital_status = '<%=marital_status%>'; //from DB you will get value 'S'. Apply this code in JSP
        document.getElementById("marital").value = marital_status;
    }